# Как изменить Бургер на стрелку и обратно в ToolBar

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Ребята, дайте рабочий пример, пожалуйста.

Cмены бургера на стрелку и обратно. И при этом чтобы бургер открывал меню, а стрелка выполняла действие "назад"

```
extends AppCompatActivity
//..

myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this, drawer, myToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Так инициализируется Toolbar:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);    
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
// так добавляем стрелку

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);           
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
//  так делаем бургер
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
    }
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    }
};
drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
drawerToggle.syncState();
```

Чтобы нажатие по стрелке действовало как назад:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```